Video Rendering Not Smooth In ScrollView
I have a basic SwiftUI scroll view that houses many videos. When I take out the red color inside the video player the scroll view is very smooth and I can swipe down and up as fast as I can without any glitches. However, when I add the red color and swipe down and then swipe up the scroll view glitches as the videos render once again. How can I fix this glitch? Also apps such as Instagram or Twitter have videos already rendered right when they appear, and scrolling away and coming back will not cause them to re-render. How can I achieve such behavior? Doing this might fix the glitch when the videos render.
Copy pasteable code
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

struct allVids: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var video: String?
}

struct MainTabViewXX: View {
    @State var someData: [allVids] = [
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F0FCE66A1-06F7-47CC-A38A-9A95192A2728.mp4?alt=media&token=57921e5a-e5e6-4b54-919b-39be9fbead84"),
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F0FCE66A1-06F7-47CC-A38A-9A95192A2728.mp4?alt=media&token=57921e5a-e5e6-4b54-919b-39be9fbead84"),
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F0FCE66A1-06F7-47CC-A38A-9A95192A2728.mp4?alt=media&token=57921e5a-e5e6-4b54-919b-39be9fbead84"),
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F0FCE66A1-06F7-47CC-A38A-9A95192A2728.mp4?alt=media&token=57921e5a-e5e6-4b54-919b-39be9fbead84"),
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F0FCE66A1-06F7-47CC-A38A-9A95192A2728.mp4?alt=media&token=57921e5a-e5e6-4b54-919b-39be9fbead84"),
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F0A514500-F1A0-4093-98A2-2847FE46484A.mp4?alt=media&token=69afd165-1ab6-4686-9ad2-2ce485090fe1"),
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2FE8937043-873E-4178-A90D-C6C03684C700.mp4?alt=media&token=ddc1f616-5427-4722-a96f-ab81739b243e"),
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2FE8937043-873E-4178-A90D-C6C03684C700.mp4?alt=media&token=ddc1f616-5427-4722-a96f-ab81739b243e"),
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2FE8937043-873E-4178-A90D-C6C03684C700.mp4?alt=media&token=ddc1f616-5427-4722-a96f-ab81739b243e"),
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2FE8937043-873E-4178-A90D-C6C03684C700.mp4?alt=media&token=ddc1f616-5427-4722-a96f-ab81739b243e"),
                allVids(id: UUID().uuidString, video: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F0FCE66A1-06F7-47CC-A38A-9A95192A2728.mp4?alt=media&token=57921e5a-e5e6-4b54-919b-39be9fbead84")]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
           LazyVStack(spacing: 1){
               ForEach(someData) { message in
                    MessageView(urlV: URL(string: message.video ?? "")!, video: message)
               }
           }
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct MessageView: View {
    @State var urlV: URL
    let video: allVids
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MessageVideoPlayerX(url: urlV, viewID: video.id)
        }
    }
}

struct MessageVideoPlayerX: View {
    @State var player: AVPlayer? = nil
    let url: URL
    @State var viewID: String
    
    init(url: URL, viewID: String? = nil) {
        self.url = url
        _viewID = State(initialValue: viewID ?? UUID().uuidString)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let vid = player {
                VidPlayer(player: vid).frame(width: 200, height: 350)
            }
            Color.red.frame(width: 200, height: 300)
        }
        .onAppear {
            if player == nil {
                player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            }
            self.player?.isMuted = true
            
            self.player?.play()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            self.player?.pause()
        }
    }
}

struct VidPlayerX : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var player : AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VidPlayerX>) -> AVPlayerViewController {

        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        controller.allowsVideoFrameAnalysis = false
        controller.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VidPlayerX>) { }
}


Note, you should not have @State var urlV: URL in your MessageView,
use let urlV: URL, and of course don't use forced unwrapping ! of anything, eg URL.
Similarly, don't use @State var viewID: String in your MessageVideoPlayerX.

Thanks @workingdogsupportUkraine, I used force unwrap to simplify this question. Assuming the State isn't the issue though.

since AVPlayer is an object it should be init inside the makeUIViewController which only happens once, not in the View hierarchy which are init many times.

Try this approach, using let player: AVPlayer instead of re-constructing one in the
.onAppear every time the MessageVideoPlayerX appears.
struct MessageVideoPlayerX: View {
    let player: AVPlayer // <--- here
    let url: URL
    let viewID: String

   init(url: URL, viewID: String? = nil) {
       self.url = url
       self.viewID = viewID ?? UUID().uuidString
       self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)  // <--- here
   }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VidPlayerX(player: player).frame(width: 200, height: 350) // <--- here
            Color.red.frame(width: 200, height: 350)
        }
       .onAppear {
           player.isMuted = true
           player.play()
       }
       .onDisappear {
           player.pause()
       }
   }
}


Works great thanks. Can you please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78447347/swift-ui-view-does-not-animate
